# can not config R Language "bzip2 library and headers are required"

Tags: r, centos

when try to run config file in R Source in Cent OS 7 ,I received the following error .
"Checking whether bzip2 support suffices ... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required".

Comment: What  commands are you using? Not sure what you mean by "running config file".

Comment: when i run the R configure from source folder of R ,i received above exception message in config progress

Comment: @user3111321 You need to be more specific; which version of R are you building from source?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the bzip2 development package to your OS. On an ubuntu system that would be:

```
sudo apt install libbz2-dev
```

and a similar incantation using CentOS' package manager should do it for you. Is it `yum` on CentOS?

Other fails during running `./config` are also possibly due to development packages being missing from your OS - look for things like `libjpeg-dev` to get JPEG image support and so on.

Comment: how did you find the name of the apt listing? I've been bouncing around SO posts like this trying to find and install all of the dependencies that R needs